# Time Dependent Workflows

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

We have a time dependent workflow on opportunity object which upon meeting the criteria schedules the following time trigger:

1. sends email 7 days before the close date
2. Sends email 2 days after the close date

If there is already an existing opportunity with close date of today and my workflow rule criteria is met. It is sending an email for the one where the time trigger is in the past (i.e. 7 days before the close date). Is there any way to avoid this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

What is your Workflow's Rule Criteria?  Have you tried:

```
CloseDate >= TODAY() + 7
```

That way if it closes today, the rule criteria will evaluate to false.